# How to inject an ASP.MVC DLL file at runtime and calls it's actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, architecture, content-management-system

I am working on a CMS and I need to make it modular. so I've created a simple controller named `TestController` that contains an action named `Index`.

How can I inject that DLL file into the main project at runtime and render `Index` action of `TestController` at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html.Action` returns `MvcHtmlString`, so you should be able to just do:

```
var html = Html.Action("MyAwesomeAction", new { foo = "bar" });
```

Comment: Thank you Chris, when I'm using the above code, visual studio intelligence  pop ups the following error message: cannot convert void to an implicitly-typed variable

Comment: actually I checked the Html.RenderAction, it's a void method and returns nothing

Comment: I did the following process to reach the goal. 1) invoke action method using system reflection 2) return the view return and store in a variable 3) render returned ViewResult to a string 4) pass result string to final view and show.

Comment: Oh, my fault. That's what I get for trying to answer a question this late at night. I got that backwards: `Html.RenderAction` writes directly to the output, while `Html.Action` returns `MvcHtmlString`.

Comment: awesome! I successfully done that using my own way (system reflection), but your approach is the best one. thank. worked for me.